# iOS TabView with Unity3D integration

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, tabview

Has anyone here been able to integrate a TabView based application with Unity3d? I have been working on a solution, but I'm beginning to believe that it may not be possible to do. The concept basically is to have the Unity3d OpenGLES view paused upon the start of the app, and have one of the tabs contain a button that un-pauses the OpenGLES view, and hides the TabView controller. Am I crazy for wanting to do this? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin called NativeToolkit  by Prime31, its free... I havent tried it, but the description says that it does exactly what you want, I tried the gamecenter plugin they offer and its amazing how easy it is to integrate, it seriously works "out of the box"

oh yeah and the NativeToolkit plugin is free too :) give it a try